# Does win10 have something like built-in code snippets?

Tags: windows, windows-10, ime

Most code editors support code snippets. But they're not available in other programs.
So I want to know if there is anything similar built into Win10 (For example, in IME).

It can be something like [U-mode input & V-mode input for Chinese IME](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/microsoft-simplified-chinese-ime-9b962a3b-2fa4-4f37-811c-b1886320dd72). (In fact, the Chinese IME does support "User defined phrases", which is not shown in the doc.) But should also work in English mode.

Answer (score 0):

- Windows has [Clipboard History](https://www.howtogeek.com/671222/how-to-enable-and-use-clipboard-history-on-windows-10/), a clipboard manager, to remember phrases and other items.
- There are numerous third-party tools, such as [CopyQ](https://github.com/hluk/CopyQ) and [alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/copyq/).